# Azure Cmdlet - New-AzureWebsite, what is different between Name and HostName?

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

**New-AzureWebsite Cmdlet -**

`New-AzureWebsite [[-Name] <String> ] [[-Location] <String> ] [[-Hostname] <String> ] [[-PublishingUsername] <String> ] [-Git] [-GitHub] [-GithubCredentials <PSCredential> ] [-GithubRepository <String> ] [-Slot <String> ] [ <CommonParameters>]`

What is the difference between `Name` and `HostName`? In what situations we can use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parameters will determine the addresses of your website.

The **`Name`** represents the website name, and it will determine the default website address allocated by Azure (it is a subdomain of azurewebsites.net).

So having the next comand:

```
New-AzureWebsite -Name MySite
```

Will generate an azure website with the next address: **`MySite.azurewebsites.net`**.

The **`Hostname`** represents additional domain name to be attached to your website. You can use it in case you have your own domain name.

So modifying the previous command:

```
New-AzureWebsite -Name MySite -Hostname MyWebsite.com
```

It will generate an azure website with the next addresses: **`MySite.azurewebsites.net`** and **`MyWebsite.com`**.

The Azure Portal equivalent operation for `Hostname` parameter is explained here - [Web Sites Custom Domain Names](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)